# One user is not able view full data on a report

Tags: reporting-services, powerbi, reportbuilder3.0

I have created a report in Report Builder and published on Power BI. One of the user is not able to view full results he gets only partial result back. I have given permission on report as well as dataset. What could be the problem. 
V.

Answer (score 0):

I see two possible problems:

1. the user is in a role with row-level security such that cannot access all data
2. the user saved the report applying some filters. Please check the filter icon on top of visualization to check if you have the same filters applied.

Comment: So, I am not sure about the row-level security. I had other users same level of security and they are able to access full report. Its just this user I added him couple of day ago.